# jquery.jqGrid.src.js - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'integer' of undefined

Tags: sharepoint, jqgrid

Im Facing the issue with JqGrid. I've gone through many suggestions and have followed the same. But, still i face the issue

jquery.jqGrid.src.js: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'integer' of undefined.

Below is the Code:

My References:

```
<script src="../../SiteAssets/Script/jquery-1.12.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../SiteAssets/Script/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../SiteAssets/Script/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../SiteAssets/Script/jquery.jqGrid.src.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../SiteAssets/Script/jquery.SPServices-0.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


var Clientdata = [];
function ClientGriddisplay() {

$("#Clientgrid").jqGrid({

        data: Clientdata,
        datatype: "local",
        colNames: ["Name","Age", "Location"],
        colModel: [

    { name: 'Name', index: 'Name', width: 200,resizable: false },
    { name: 'Age', index: 'Age', width: 200,resizable: false },
    { name: 'Location', index: 'Location', width: 200,resizable: false },
        ],
        rowNum: 10,
        mtype:'Get',
        loadonce:true,
        rowList:[10,20,30],
        pager:'#jQGridDemoPager',
        sortname: 'id',
        viewrecords: true,
        sortorder: "desc",
        caption: "Personal Details",
        height:'auto',
        gridview:true
    });

}

$('#document').ready(function () {

    //To load the client data from the sharepoint list.
    GetClientList();
    //To load the client data to the JQgrid
    ClientGriddisplay();
});

function GetClientList() {
    $().SPServices({
        operation: "GetListItems",
        async: false,
        listName: "GridTest",
        CAMLViewFields: "",
        completefunc: buildClientarray
    });
}

function buildClientarray(xData, status) {

    $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function () {      
        Clientdata.push({
            Name: $(this).attr("ows_Name"),
            Age: $(this).attr("ows_Age"),
            Location: $(this).attr("ows_Location"),
        });
    });

}
```

[image]

Comment: Which version of jqGrid you use and from which fork ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7)? If you don't yet use free jqGrid 4.13.1 I recommend you to change URLs to jqGrid files (CSS and JS) to URLs described in [the wiki article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs). If you get the error, please use `jquery.jqgrid.src.js` instead of `jquery.jqgrid.min.js` and to write the line of `jquery.jqgrid.src.js` where the error take place.

Comment: Hi, I've used jquery.jqgrid.min.js from CDN (considering as free jqgrid). Also, i've used both the jquery.jqgrid.src.js & jquery.jqgrid.min.js and then jquery.jqgrid.src.js. Still the issue persists. I've included the references in the top. Can you figure out the issue ? Or should i use jquery.fmatter.js ?

Comment: **What version of jqGrid you use?** One should include *only* one file: either `jquery.jqGrid.min.js` or `jquery.jqGrid.src.js`. Could you replace `href` of `<link` with `ui.jqgrid.css` to `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/free-jqgrid/4.13.1/css/ui.jqgrid.css` and `src` of `<script src=...>` to `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/free-jqgrid/4.13.1/js/jquery.jqgrid.scr.js` and to comment scipt with `grid.locale-en.js` which is unneeded with free jqGrid 4.13.1. If you get an error then you can start Developer Tools (press F12) and start debugger. You will see line number of the error.

Comment: I don't see `<script>` before `var Clientdata = [];` and `</script>` at the end of the code. What is `$('#document')`? You should replace `$('#document').ready(function () {` with `$(function () {` or to `$(document).ready(function () {`

Comment: the above is not the format of my coding. I've copy pasted only the codes. the <Script> tag is present in the custom NewPage. I Will try replacing the $(document).ready(function()){. And, FYI i've implemented the same code in my local system(onpermise with 100+ items). That works fine. but, im trying the same with o365 which has 500+ items.